# Synaptics clickpad keys occassionally messed up on X240

Tags: touchpad, suspend, thinkpad, synaptics, button

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 on my Lenovo Thinkpad X240. Since I dislike the new clickpad and because I use the trackpoint always anyway, I disabled the trackpad functionality and only kept the button functionality active as discribed in various tutorials on the internet:

```
# $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-x240-clickpad.conf
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "tp only with clickpad buttons"
    MatchDriver "synaptics"
    Option "ClickPad" "1"
    Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
    Option "SoftButtonAreas" "60% 0 0 0 40% 59% 0 0" #Emulate right and midle buttons

    Option "TouchpadOff" "2"
    Option "AreaBottomEdge" "1" #disable moving but not buttons
EndSection
```

This works rather fine. However, sometimes the buttons are not recognized: There is middle-button on the whole left + middle part then, or maybe right button on the complete area, or similar messe.

I suspect this happens after waking up from suspend, but only sometimes and not immediately after resume. I can sometimes fix the behavior by executing another suspend/resume cycle and sometimes it fixes itself after a couple of minutes.

There are no significant errors in the syslog which I can assign to the shown behavior.

Does anyone have a clue what is going wrong and hopefully how I can fix it?